# I am having trouble adding external JAR to Android project in NBandroid (NetBeans 7.0.1)

Tags: android, netbeans, jar

I am new to both Java development and Android development. Did a couple of regular Java projects in NetBeans and liked the IDE. Then tried Eclipse and did not like it. I am trying to develop for Android using the NBandroid plugin but ran into a strange problem.

All I want is to add an external JAR to the project. Say, I have a jar in c:\foo\bar.jar (I am on WinXP by the way). For a regular project in Netbeans, all you do is right-click on Libraries, select Add Jar/Folder and you're good to go.

I can't do it in my Android project. I click on Libs but nothing happens. If I am doing something wrong, what is it?

If I am doing it right, can I manually override this by entering the JAR info into the build file(s)? I tried this by looking at the build files for a regular project in NetBeans but could not map it easily into the Android project since the build file structure seems to be different.

If I can't figure this one out, I will have to abandon NetBeans and go back to Eclipse, but I want to give it a shot. Can you provide any advice? Thank much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but in case anyone stumbles over it, you can manually drag .jar files into the "/libs" subfolder of your Android project's folder using an operating system file manager like Windows Explorer, and they will show up inside NetBeans under "Libraries" as if you added them the usual way.